# How to get a specific publication details with metadata values using TOM .NET API and passing the publication name?

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, event-system, content-manager, tom.net

I want to get a specific publication details including metadata using TOM.NET API by just passing the Title of the publication? Could you help me with the best way (which method to use etc.)?

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1.
Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Use a WebDAV url. "/WebDAV/publication%20name" - escape spaces and dots.

Comment: Sounds like an Answer, Nuno.

Answer (score 2):

As Nuno mentioned in the comment, but I'll steal his points by making it an answer ;o). In Template code you can use the `GetObject` method directly from the `Engine` object available in a Template:

```
Publication pub = (Publication)engine.GetObject("/WebDAV/Publication%20Name");
```

If your code is used in an Event Handler, you can use the `GetObject` method from the `Session` object, which you get from the `subject` (item the event is triggered on):

```
Publication pub = (Publication)subject.Session.GetObject("/WebDAV/Publication%20Name");
```